# Что означает точка перед переменной в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Может кто разъяснить, что означает точка в данном фрагменте кода?
**.filter
.reduceRight**

```
console.log(

 [1, 4, 3, 0, 4, 5, 4]
   
   .filter(element => !(element % 2))
   
   .reduceRight((accumulator, element) => accumulator + Math.sqrt(element), 0)
); // 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это синтаксис обращения к методу объекта (а также свойству тоже). В данном случае у массива есть метод  filter, который вызывается по отношению к этому массиву. Аналогично с reduceRight

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за ответ. Из-за невнимательности проглядел, что здесь идет обращение.

Comment: "а также свойству тоже" - что-то здесь лишнее

Answer (score 3):

Точка в выражениях разделяет объект и его свойство/метод.

Здесь сначала выполняется вызов метода `filter` исходного массива; а затем вызов метода `reduceRight` массива возвращенного методом `filter`.
То есть, это цепочка вызовов, одно выражение составленное из нескольких: в этом общем выражении вызывается метод того объекта, который получен вычислением предыдущего подвыражения. Вычисление подвыражений выполняется слева направо (оператор вызова, "скобки" - имеет больший приоритет, чем оператор доступа к свойству, "точка").

Желательно оформлять код по-человечески: потому что если делать это, то подобные вопросы сами собой отпадают.
Вот в данном случае, горизонтальные отступы (пустые строки) совершенно неуместны - они визуально "разрывают" цепочку вызовов, хотя это **одно** составное выражение (а не три независимых).